# What steps do I follow to run a stock Hello World CGI script?

Tags: development, apache2, lamp, webapp-development

Assume I have finished installing a modern release of stock Ubuntu, and have the following script.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html\n"
echo "<html><body>Hello world</body></html>"
```

How do I install and configure Apache to serve a "Hello world" web page from http://localhost using this script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The Quick Way

#### Install the Apache web server

In the command line (Terminal) application:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

#### Make your script executable by Apache

For this example we'll assume the CGI script is named `test.sh` and is saved in your personal home folder. For Apache to use `test.sh`, the script first needs to have executable permissions:

```
chmod 755 $HOME/test.sh
```

It also needs to be moved to the Apache-designated CGI folder. *For Ubuntu (and other Debian-based operating systems), this is* `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/`, while HTML and other content is stored in `/var/www`.

```
sudo mv $HOME/test.sh /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
```

#### Visit the output at your local server

Apache will serve the `test.sh`-generated HTML at http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.sh. If Apache is located somewhere besides your own machine, replace 'localhost' with the URL or IP address of the server.

### Storing CGI scripts in /var/www/test-cgi rather than /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

You need to modify the vanilla Apache configuration to store CGI scripts at another folder.

```
sudoedit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

Add the following inside the `<VirtualHost>` directive:

```
ScriptAlias /test-cgi/ /var/www/test-cgi/
<Directory "/var/www/test-cgi">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then, in the command line:

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/test-cgi
sudoedit /var/www/test-cgi/test.sh
```

Then, in the command line, restart Apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

As with *The Quick Way*, the CGI output should be served at http://localhost/test-cgi/test.sh (replace "localhost" with the server domain if you're developing remotely).

### Troubleshooting

If you have problems, consult [the official Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html#configuring).

Comment: Note to friendly Apache gurus: It would be nice for this answer to cover a few more configurations besides /usr/lib/cgi_bin and /var/www/test_cgi/ (eg the $HOME/public_html option).