# How do I install and run Apache2?

Tags: installation, apache2, web-development, ulimit

I have downloaded `apache2` from the [official site](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache22) and compiled and installed it per the given instructions there, but on running I get an error:

```
 ulimit: 88: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
 /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 148: /usr/sbin/apache2: not found
 The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: Why didn't you install the apache package from the ubuntu repos? (just run `sudo apt-get install apache2` in a terminal) Does the error log provide more information as mentioned? (look at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`)

Comment: i have installed as you stold but while running i am getting an erro like
    ulimit: 88: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)  
    apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully                    qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
    (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address     0.0.0.0:80
     no listening sockets available, shutting down
     Unable to open logs
     Action 'start' failed.
     The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: any command to uninstall the previous apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just install the repository version:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Start it running like this:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Assuming it's working, you should see a basic greeting at http://localhost/. If you're looking for CGI scripting, I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/86802/24694) helpful; otherwise you can start putting static content to serve in `/var/www/` or configuring the operation of Apache with `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Comment: * Restarting web server apache2                                                apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
 ... waiting .apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
                                                                         [ OK ] 



i got this and apache is running thanks

Comment: I've had a similar problem to the OP, however I did install it using the `sudo apt-get install apache2` command. When I run `sudo service apache2 restart` it gives me an error: 

`No apache MPM package installed`